# How to forward a mailing list to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, email, mailing-list

I have a subscription to a public mailing list, but I would prefer to read the messages in my twitter stream rather than in my inbox.

My idea was to forward the e-mails to a blogging system which supports auto-posting to twitter. Both posterous.com and wordpress.com can do that, but they only accept posting via e-mails from known (and registered) addresses.

Do you have any other idea? Can you think of another approach? Did I overlook something?

**[update]**

Tweetymail is also no (usable) solution. When wordpress.com or posterous post to twitter, the tweet contains the mail's subject line and a link to the post where one can read the body of the mail. Tweetymail uses a similar concept, but removes all the newlines in the body text, which renders the body (imho) so badly readable, that I rather don't want to use their service.

Comment: I haven't tested it, so I will not post it as an answer, but take a look at [tweetymail](http://tweetymail.com/).

Comment: Also, if you forward the emails to wordpress or posterous, the only email address that you have to register with them is the one forwarding the emails, so where is the problem?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the input. I added a sentence to tweetymail to the original question. Regarding you second point, I use gmail, which leave the sender address intact when forwarding, so that the sender address is still from the person who sent to the mailing list in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new service [iftt.com](http://iftt.com) allows me to do what I planned. It is very easy.

I connected  iftt.com with my gmail account and my wordpress account. When a mail comes in from the mailing list, it is automatically labeled by filters in gmail. iftt then checks for e-mails with this label and posts these mails in my wordpress blog. The wordpress blog is than connected with my twitter account and tweets the new posts. Voila!

Sidenote:  You don't have to use gmail. Iftt also accepts forwarded mails from all other providers. Also one can also forward these mails to Tumblr and Posterous, who also support auto tweeting.

cheers